# focusInEvent not called in QLineEdit subclass

Tags: c++, qt, focus, qtextedit

I have a Qt/cpp code and display a subclassed `QLineEdit`. When double-clicking the `QLineEdit`, the `focusInEvent` is never called (launched in Maya).

```
void myQLineEditClass::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
    MGlobal::displayInfo(MQtUtil::toMString(QString().sprintf("HERE")));
    QLineEdit::focusInEvent(e);
}
```

HERE is never displayed, event if the `focusInEvent` is present in the .h protect part. Any idea how to get focusInEvents ?

Comment: Have you set the focus policy on the widget?

Comment: Worked fine for me. (Not in Maya)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was linked to the fact that the QLineEdit was in a QGraphicsView that was in another QGraphicsView. Bringing the QLineEdit to the higher-level QGraphicsView made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below. For several occasions that worked for me when focusInEvent did not.

```
void YourWidget::changeEvent(QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::ActivationChange)
    {
        if (isActiveWindow())
        {
             // gaining the focus
        }
        else
        {
             // loosing the focus
        }
    }

    // or whatever *parent* class call is
    QWidget::changeEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The event gets intercepted by the editor widget. See `QItemDelegate::createEditor`. The widget returned there will get it.